# Error when using purrr to scrape multiple pages

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest, purrr

I am attempting to scrape multiple web pages (like this: https://www.foreign.senate.gov/hearings/120314am) that are set up in similar ways. The function I created works when using one url, but when try mapping over multiple pages it gives me an error.

Here is a simplified version of the function.

```
scrape <- function(url){
   url <- paste0("https://www.foreign.senate.gov/hearings/", hearing_name)

      product <- url %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_nodes("#main_column")

      names <- product %>%
      html_nodes(".fn") %>%
      html_text() %>% 
      gsub("\\n", "",.) %>% 
      gsub("\\t", "",.) 

      tibble(Witness_Name = names)
    }
```

When storing the urls into an object and trying to map I get the error.

```
hearing_name <- c("the-ebola-epidemic-the-keys-to-success-for-the-international-response",
              "120314am")

map_df(hearing_name, scrape)


Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=2].
```

I have tried using lapply() and reorganizing for a minimalist approach but no luck. Hope some one can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function, there is a hard-coded hearing_name instead of 'url'

```
url <- paste0("https://www.foreign.senate.gov/hearings/", hearing_name)
```

If we change that to url

```
scrape <- function(url){
   url <- paste0("https://www.foreign.senate.gov/hearings/", url)

      product <- url %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_nodes("#main_column")

      names <- product %>%
      html_nodes(".fn") %>%
      html_text() %>% 
      gsub("\\n", "",.) %>% 
      gsub("\\t", "",.) 

      tibble(Witness_Name = names)
    }
```

the code would work fine

```
out <- map_df(hearing_name, scrape)
dim(out)
#[1] 8 1
out
# A tibble: 8 x 1
#  Witness_Name        
#  <chr>               
#1 Ellen JohnsonSirleaf
#2 PaulFarmer          
#3 AnnePeterson        
#4 PapeGaye            
#5 JavierAlvarez       
#6 DanielRussel        
#7 Richard C.Bush III  
#8 SophieRichardson
```